# Facebook Connect button question - please help

Tags: javascript, css, templates, facebook

```
<fb:login-button onlogin="window.location = '/custompage.html';">Connect</fb:login-button>
```

That's currently my code for users to log in to my site. It's in FBML.

It will pop up a box, the user then logs in. And then, it closes the new window, followed by a redirect to "**custompage.html**".

Now, I would like to manually render my button instead of using FBML, because it's too slow on mobile" http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Connect_Login_Buttons#Facebook_Connect_for_iPhone_Buttons

**How do I close the popup window and redirect**, using this code as explained in the doc?:

```
<a href="" onclick="FB.Connect.requireSession();return false;"><img src="http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/images/6/6f/Connect_iphone.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you want run on successful login should be passed as an argument to `requireSession()`.  In your case, I believe you want

```
<a href="" onclick="FB.Connect.requireSession(function () {
    window.location = '/custompage.html'
  });return false;">
  <img src="http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/images/6/6f/Connect_iphone.png">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.
put this inside the requireSession:

```
function() { window.location='/'; }
```